# Android Linkify doesn't work

Tags: java, android

Hi all I have the follow code:

```
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Pattern.compile("http://www.abc.com"),"http://www.abc.com?m=signup");
```

Problem is I keep getting directed to the "http://www.abc.com" page instead of the sign-up page, anyone knows why?

Solution:
Thanks for the hint Noel, was able to solve it doing this.

```
TransformFilter transformFilter = new TransformFilter() {
    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
        return "";
    }
};
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Pattern.compile("http://www.abc.com"),
        "http://www.abc.com/?m=signup",null ,transformFilter);
```

Comment: What does your textview contain?

Comment: I doubt it is the problem, but you are missing a / between com and ?

Comment: @Matthieu didn't work.
@Noel "Blah blah blah ...sign-up for a free web account at http://www.abc.com" there is a http ://www in front of abc.com stackoverflow changing it to url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your tv content to contain the full link instead of just abc.com. In your `addLinks()` call, the last argument is the scheme which is usually something like `http://`, it's not the address that the links will go to.

See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks%28android.widget.TextView,%20java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String%29) for more details. They also have an explanation at the top of what is expected.

Comment: So what is wrong with my code? My text does contain http://www and I thought I specified the link as the scheme? The pattern is getting highlighted correctly, just wondering why it does not direct to the signup page and rather to just www abc.com like the signup page never existed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you've solved this one, but I know that this will work:

```
final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("http://www.my.url.com?hey=nice");
Linkify.addLinks(ss, Linkify.WEB_URLS);  
twitterURL.setText(ss);
twitterURL.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is very old and may not work for recent versions of Android

Comment: Tested on Android Nougat and looks like it still helps.

Comment: Good to hear - I think I misread your comment and thought you said it wasn't working :)